# conversion of string to tuple in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, numpy, tuples

I have a tuple (h) as follows:

```
(array([[145,  34,  26,  18,  90,  89],
   [ 86, 141, 216, 167,  67, 214],
   [ 18,   0, 212,  49, 232,  34],
   ...,
   [147,  99,  73, 110, 108,   9],
   [222, 133, 231,  48, 227, 154],
   [184, 133, 169, 201, 162, 168]], dtype=uint8), array([[178,  58,  24,  90],
   [  3,  31, 129, 243],
   [ 48,  92,  19, 108],
   ...,
   [148,  21,  25, 209],
   [189, 114,  46, 218],
   [ 15,  43,  92,  61]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 17, 254, 216, ..., 126,  74, 129],
   [231, 168, 214, ..., 131,  50, 107],
   [ 77, 185, 229, ...,  86, 167,  61],
   ...,
   [105, 240,  95, ..., 230, 158,  27],
   [211,  46, 193, ...,  48,  57,  79],
   [136, 126, 235, ..., 109,  33, 185]], dtype=uint8))
```

I converted it into a string s = str(h):

```
'(array([[  1,  60, 249, 162,  51,   3],\n       [ 57,  76, 193, 244,  17, 238],\n       [ 22,  72, 101, 229, 185, 124],\n       ...,\n       [132, 243, 123, 192, 152, 107],\n       [163, 187, 131,  47, 253, 155],\n       [ 21,   3,  77, 208, 229,  15]], dtype=uint8), array([[119, 149, 215, 129],\n       [146,  71, 121,  79],\n       [114, 148, 121, 140],\n       ...,\n       [175, 121,  81,  71],\n       [178,  92,   1,  99],\n       [ 80, 122, 189, 209]], dtype=uint8), array([[ 26, 122, 248, ..., 104, 167,  29],\n       [ 41, 213, 250, ...,  82,  71, 211],\n       [ 20, 122,   4, ..., 152,  99, 121],\n       ...,\n       [133,  77,  84, ..., 238, 243, 240],\n       [208, 183, 187, ..., 182,  51, 116],\n       [ 19, 135,  48, ..., 210, 163,  58]], dtype=uint8))'
```

Now, I want to convert s back to a tuple. I tried using ast.literal_eval(s), but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 84, in literal_eval
return _convert(node_or_string)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 55, in _convert
return tuple(map(_convert, node.elts))
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 83, in _convert
raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x76a6f770>
```

I could not find this exact solution anywhere. It would be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: **Why** are you converting a tuple with numpy arrays to a string? What higher-level problem are you trying to solve by doing that?

Comment: And no, `ast.literal_eval()` is very limited, slow, and only useful for a subset of Python's built-in types. It should not be seen as a production-level tool, anyway.

Comment: I want to store this tuple in a database and I felt converting it into a string and then storing it would be simpler. Please suggest if you have a better way?

Comment: If you want to store it as an opaque datablob, just use the `pickle` module.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `str()` on numpy arrays (wrapped in tuples or otherwise) and hope to recover the data.

First of all, the `ast.literal_eval()` function only supports [literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#literals) and [literal displays](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries), not numpy `array(...)` syntax.

Next, `str()` on a tuple produces *debugging-friendly output*; tuples don't implement a `__str__` string conversion hook, so their `repr()` representation is returned instead. Numpy arrays do support `str()` conversion, but their output is still but a friendly-looking string that omits a lot of detail from the actual values. In your example, those `...` [ellipsis dots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) indicate that there is more data in that part of the array, but the strings *do not include those values*. So you are losing data if you were to try to re-create your arrays from this.

If you need to store these tuples in a file or database column, or need to transmit them over a network connection, you need to *serialise* the data. Proper serialisation will preserve every detail of the arrays.

For tuples with numpy arrays, you can use [`pickle.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) to produce a `bytes` object that can be passed back to [`pickles.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads) to recreate the same value.

You can also convert invidual numpy arrays to a numpy-specific binary format, and load that format again, with the [`numpy.save()` and `numpy.load()` functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html) (which operate directly on files, but you can pass in [`io.BytesIO()` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO)).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I used numpy.save() and numpy.load() and it worked.